# nginx configuration when using websocket and http?

Tags: c#, nginx, websocket

I want to do websocket load balancing with Nginx. The server (MyServer) is written in C# and port 8080 is opened for both websocket requests and http requests:

```
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (context.Request.Path == "/wsDataImport")
            {
                if (context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
                {
                    WebSocket webSocket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    await WebSocketHandler.DataImportHandler(context, webSocket).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
                }
            }
            else if (context.Request.Path == "/wsBroadcast")
            {
                if (context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
                {
                    WebSocket webSocket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    await WebSocketHandler.BroadcastHandler(context, webSocket).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await next().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        });
```

Without Nginx, I can start websocket connection in frontend (js file) like this and the test is OK:

```
        const ws1 = new WebSocket("ws://{IP}:8080/wsDataImport")
        const ws2 = new WebSocket("ws://{IP}:8080/wsBroadcast")
```

With Nginx, I change it to:

```
        const ws1 = new WebSocket("ws://ws/wsDataImport")
        const ws2 = new WebSocket("ws://ws/wsBroadcast")
```

And part of the nginx configuration is:

```
location /ws/ {
    proxy_pass http://{IP}:8080/;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

But I get this error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://ws/wsBroadcast' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Can anyone give me some help about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is that a typo or are you actually trying to connect to `ws://ws/wsDataImport` (without specifying a host or port)

Comment: I’m actually trying to connect to ws://{IP}:8080/wsDataImport(with host and port). But with Nginx, I think it's ok to not specify host and port in the code. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I know the reason...
Since Nginx listens to port 80, I should send the request to {localIP}:80 in the code. So in frontend (js file), it should be:

```
const ws1 = new WebSocket("ws://" + location.host + "/ws/wsDataImport")
const ws2 = new WebSocket("ws://" + location.host + "/ws/wsBroadcast")
```